# Meteor. Problems with subscribe/publish

Tags: meteor

i have a problem.
I'm trying to build highcharts graphic.
How it works: 
I'm going to my route ('ship.details'), and here i have not problems.
My problem:
subsription to (ships_snapshots_all) not working.
My publish.js:

```
Meteor.publish("ships_snapshots", function(user, options) {
    if(!this.userId) return null;
    if(this.userId) {
        console.log('subsribed by ' + user);
        return ships_snapshots.find({userId: user}, options);
    }
});
Meteor.publish("ships_snapshots_all", function() {
    return ships_snapshots.find({});
})
```

My subscribe.js (in lib folder):

```
Meteor.subscribe('ships_snapshots');
Meteor.subscribe('ships_snapshots_all');
```

Problem 100% in my subsription, because if i'm installing autopublish all working good. And problem in my router i think.

router.js:

```
Router.route('/ships/details', {
    name: 'ship.details',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    onBeforeAction: function() {
        var shipId = Session.get('currentShipId');
        if(!shipId) {
            Router.go('user.ships');
        } else {
            this.next();
        }
    },
    waitOn: function() {

        if (Meteor.isClient) {
        var getCompare = Meteor.user().profile.wows.compareWith;
        console.log(getCompare);
        var user2 = Meteor.users.findOne({"profile.wows.nickname": getCompare});
        var user2Id = user2._id;
        if (getCompare) {
            var user2 = Meteor.users.findOne({"profile.wows.nickname": getCompare});
            if (user2) {
                var user2Id = user2._id;
            }
        }
        if (getCompare) {
            var handle = Meteor.subscribe('ships_snapshots', Meteor.user()._id) && Meteor.subscribe('ships_snapshots', user2Id) && Meteor.subscribe('userSearchInfo', getCompare);
            Session.set('compareWith', user2);
            console.log('user2 _____');
            console.log(user2);
            return handle
        } else {
            var handle = Meteor.subscribe('ships_snapshots', Meteor.user()._id) && Meteor.subscribe('ships_snapshots', user2Id);
            return handle
        }
    }, data: function() {
            if (handle.ready()) {
            var shipname = this.params.shipName;
            var obj = {};

            var query = ships.findOne(); 
            var shipId = Session.get('currentShipId');
            var result;
            _.each(Meteor.user().profile.wows.ships, function(row) {
                if (row.ship_id === shipId) {
                    result = row;
                }
            });     
            return result;
        }
    }
});
```

I think my problem in subscripion for ship_snapshots. Something going wrong here, but i can't to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "not working"? From your code I would assume that you're always seeing all the ship snapshots.

You shouldn't have the subscribes in /lib if you have them in your router. If you have `Meteor.subscribe('ships_snapshots_all');` in /lib then you should always be seeing all the ship snapshots (assuming you're not stopping that subscription anywhere).

Also your subscription to all should be:

```
Meteor.publish("ships_snapshots", function(user, options) {
    if(this.userId) {
        console.log('subsribed by ' + user);
        return ships_snapshots.find({userId: user}, options);
    } else this.ready();
});
```

You don't want to return null when there is no user, you can just mark the subscription as ready without finding any records. This is not the cause of your problem but just good practice.

Comment: Thank you Michel, you answer is really helped me, and i'm found the main problem: i have been not subscribed to user2 information properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
Meteor.publish("ships_snapshots", function(user, options) {
    if(!this.userId) return null;
    if(this.userId) {
        console.log('subsribed by ' + user);
        return ships_snapshots.find({userId: user._id}, options);
    }
});
```

In your publish script, is user really an id or is it a user object? I changed it to user._id. Please check that.

Comment: Thank you for reply. As you can see, in router.js i'm passing user2Id variable ( === user2._id) to publish function, so problem not here.

Comment: Your options for ships_snapshots are always undefined. Is that on purpose?

Comment: In my graphic i'm need to get data of second user for compare some data with him, so i'm tryed to make subsctiption in router.js (but it is not working), so i'm just added Meteor.subscribe('ships_snapshots_all') (this publish all data); to subscribe.js, but it is still not working..